# How to get the default value of dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html

How do i get the `defaultValue` or `value` of a checkbox and dropdown? For textbox and textarea i use:

html:

```
<input type="text" id="txtbox_id" class="input-text" />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
<br />
<select id="select" name="select">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function check() {
    var default1    = document.getElementById("txtbox_id").defaultValue;
    var change1     = document.getElementById("txtbox_id").value;
    var default2    = document.getElementById("checkbox1").defaultValue;
    var change2     = document.getElementById("checkbox1").value;
    var default3    = document.getElementById("select").defaultValue;
    var change3     = document.getElementById("select").value;
    if (change1 == default1 && change2 == default2 && change3 == default3) {
        alert('Not Changed!');
    } else {
        alert('Changed!');
    }
}
```

I'm using this to check if the value in the form has been changed or not. But I am getting an error when i use this code to check for checkbox and dropdown. Please suggest me the right method to achieve this.

Comment: Have you checked out `selectedIndex`?

Comment: Please provide more context. A piece of HTML, how the events are attached, what do you do with the read values. I mean either of the lines in the post won't cause an error, unless an element with `id="txtbox_id"` can't be found from the document.

Comment: output your default value(s) to a js var on page load and then compare to that

Comment: @Teemu I have added a few lines of code. I call the javascript function from button `onClick` event

Comment: Hmm.. Not yet an error source in the code (assuming the missing quote in HTML being a typo in the post), what is the error message? Thought `default2` and `change2` would both be `undefined`, please see Niet the Dark Absol's answer to correct this.

Comment: that missing quote is a typo :D and actually there's no error in code,the values of dropdown and checkbox show as `undefined` and i wanted to know if i could pull the value of the select/checkbox instead of it.

Answer (score 4):

Check their attributes. When a user modifies a form, it affects the *properties*, but the attributes remain intact.

```
var checkbox_defaultChecked = document.getElementById('some_checkbox').getAttribute("checked");
```

Selects are a bit harder:

```
var selectbox_defaultOption = document.querySelector("#some_dropdown option[selected]");
```

Note that you will need a shim or more complicated code for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

for checkbox:

//this checks if checkbox is checked or not and returns `true` and `false`

```
var default_checked = document.getElementById("checkbox_id").defaultChecked;
var checked_change  = document.getElementById("checkbox_id").checked;
```

for dropdown:

//this gets the default value and changed value of dropdown

```
var select_  = document.querySelector('select[id="dropdown_id"] option[selected]');
var default_ = select1.value;
var change_  = document.getElementById("os_cd").value;
```